# Wildcard beginning of a line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

How to use wildcard for beginning of a line? 
Example, I want to replace `abc` with `def`.

This is what my file looks like

```
     abc
    abc
abc
hg  abc
```

Now I want that `abc` should be replaced in only first 3 lines. How to do it?

```
$_ =~ s/['\s'] * abc ['\s'] * /def/g;
```

What condition to be put before beginning of first space?

Thanks

Comment: can you please show like your output?

Comment: Please note `\s` does not match just spaces, but also other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_ =~ s/^['\s'] * abc ['\s'] * /def/g;
```

If you need to check from start of a line then use `^`.

Also, I am not sure why you have `'` and spaces in your regex. This should also work for you:

```
$_ =~ s/^[\s]*abc[\s]*/def/g;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks... I was using '^' in bracket, hence it wasn't working.

Comment: Also this will get rid of the leading spaces. This behavior is not specified in the question, but I guess this is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: This is too complicated; for simpler solution to @bookishq problem see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340206/684229)

Comment: @Tomas you just copied my answer posted 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @m0skit0, why would I copy your answer that was buggy from the beginning and still is? :-) Note that you still need to replace the `$` with `\\` :-)

Comment: Nope, I don't need to replace anything, it works fine. Learn the language syntax before saying nonsense. And also no, it was never buggy ;)

Comment: @m0skit0, what about the `\)` in the [before you corrected it](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17339964/1)?

Comment: See the question [before it was corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17339862/1) ;) Anyway, no hard feelings, I'll even upvote your answer. Have a nice day :^)

Comment: @m0skit0, OK, sorry :-) And I see `$1` also works as perl backreference, surprisingly. Upvoting you as a revenge :D

Comment: @Tomas And btw thank you for showing me that `\1` is also a valid backreference ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
s/(^ *)abc/$1def/g
```

`(^ *)` -> zero or morespaces at start of line

This will **strictly** replace abc with def.

Also note I've used a real space and not `\s` because you said *"beginning of first space"*. `\s` matches more characters than only space.

Comment: I don't think those `1)` was supposed to be in the input.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a couple of mistakes in your regex

```
$_ =~ s/['\s'] * abc ['\s'] * /def/g;
```

- You don't need `/g` (*global*, match as many times as possible) if you only want to replace from the beginning of the string (since that can only match once).
- Inside a character class bracket all characters are literal except `]`, `-` and `^`, so `['\s']` means "match whitespace or apostrophe `'`"
- Spaces inside the regex is interpreted literally, unless the `/x` modifier is used (which it is not)
- Quantifiers apply to whatever they immediately precede, so `\s*` means "zero or more whitespace", but `\s *` means "exactly one whitespace, followed by zero or more space". Again, unless `/x` is used.
- You do not need to supply `$_ =~`, since that is the variable any regex uses unless otherwise specified.

If you want to replace `abc`, and only `abc` when it is the first non-whitespace in a line, you can do this:

```
s/^\s*\Kabc/def/
```

An alternate for the `\K` (keep) escape is to capture and put back

```
s/^(\s*)abc/$1def/
```

If you want to keep the whitespace following the target string `abc`, you do not need to do anything. If you want it removed, just add `\s*` at the end

```
s/^\s*\Kabc\s*/def/
```

Also note that this is simply a way to condense logic into one statement. You can also achieve the same by using very simple building blocks:

```
if (/^\s*abc/) {    # if abc is the first non-whitespace
    s/abc/def/;     # ...substitute it
}
```

Since the substitution only happens once (if the `/g` modifier is not used), and only the first match is affected, this will flawlessly substitute `abc` for `def`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` character, and remove unnecessary apostrophes, spaces and `[` `]` :

```
$_ =~ s/^\s*abc/def/g
```

If you want to keep those spaces that were before the "abc":

```
$_ =~ s/^(\s*)abc/\1def/g
```